# recursively count lines with delimited pattern

Tags: linux, sorting, unix, command-line, hierarchy

Let's say I have a file that contained:

foo/bar
foo/bar/thing0
foo/bar/thing1
...
foo/bar/thing10
foo/bar1/thing0
foo/bar1
foo/bar2/thing2
foo/bar1/thing1/subthing1
foo/bar1/thing1/subthing2
...

I would like to generate a hierarchical view that gives me the counts of the "sublines". That is to say, the output will look like:

foo - 100
foo/bar - 20
foo/bar/thing0 - 8
...
foo/bar1 - 20
foo/bar1/thing0 - 10
foo/bar2 - 60
foo/bar2/thing2 - 1

And allow this to be configurable. For example, I can limit it to only count the occurrences of */*/ (delimited by '/').

I've done this with a perl script before but I was wondering whether there's a method using the tcsh command line and some standard unix utilities to do it.

Answer (score 0):

For each level of depth you can do it with standard unix tools:

Level 1 (foo):

```
cut -d/ -f1 < FILE | sort | uniq -c
```

Level 2 (foo/bar):

```
cut -d/ -f-2 < FILE | sort | uniq -c
```

Level 3 (foo/bar/thin1)

```
cut -d/ -f-3 < FILE | sort | uniq -c
```

And so on